# Idle time of a process in Linux

Tags: linux, time, process, python-idle, procfs

I need to calculate CPU usage (user mode, system mode, idle time) of a process in Linux.
I am able to calculate usage in user and system mode using `utime` and `stime` values from `/proc/PID/stat`, but I found nothing which is related to idle time.

I know I can get idle time from `/proc/stat` but this value is related to machine, not for particular process.

Is it possible to calculate idle time of a process knowing its `PID` (reading data from `/proc` directory)?

Comment: The idle time for a CPU is the time it did not execute any (useful) code. What exactly is the idle time of a process?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand idle time of a process as a time when process CPU usage (both in user and system mode) is 0%.

Comment: How do you count the time when the process is running on several cores thru several threads?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about it but maybe the following works:

```
1) Get the process start up time. Im sure thats possible
2) Generate time difference (dTime = CurrentTime - TimeProcessStarted)
3) Substract the time the process is running ( dTime - (usageSystemMode + usageUserMode))
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: I think your solution will work:) Process start up time can be retrieved from /proc/PID/stat using starttime value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's too late but, I guessed this command useful:

```
IFS=$'\n';for i in `ps -eo uname:20,pid,cmd | grep -v "USER\|grep\|root"`; \
do if [ $(id -g `echo $i | cut -d" " -f1`) -gt 1000 ] && \
[ $(echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date -d "$(ll -u \ 
--time-style=+"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" /proc/$(echo $i | \
awk '{print $2}')/cwd | awk '{print $6" "$7}')" +%s))/3600))) >=1 ]; \
then echo $i; fi; done
```

to use it in bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `ps -eo uname:20,pid,cmd | grep -v "USER\|grep\|root"`
do 
  Name="`echo $i | cut -d' ' -f1`"
  Id="$(id -g $Name)"
  Pid="`echo $i | awk '{print $2}'`"
  Time1=$(date +%s)
  Time2=$(date -d "$(/usr/bin/ls -lu --time-style=+"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" \
 /proc/$Pid/cwd | awk '{print $6" "$7}')" +%s)/3600
  Time=$Time1-$Time2
  if [ $Id -gt 1000 ] && [ $Time >=1 ]
  then 
    echo $i
  fi

done
```

you could change *grep -v "grep\|root"* as you wish.
this one line command list all processes which not root owner or system users.