# Calculating idlness of a process in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a specific process with a specific id,
I've been looking to some posts that suggests grepping on the /proc/PID/stat and doing some calculation between the utime and the stime..
I was wondering if there was an easier way to do that, that measures the idleness time for that specific process...

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053236/idle-time-of-a-process-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was an easier way to do that

What could be easier than this?

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=${1?usage: $0 <pid>}
set -- $(</proc/$pid/stat); utime=${14}; stime=${15}; starttime=${22?}
set $(</proc/uptime); uptime=${1/./}
idletime=$((uptime-starttime-utime-stime))
echo $idletime
```